# How compare elements of lists when lists are stored as strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [ "B,C,D"
         "W,F,G"
         "M,S,E"
       ]
arr2 = [E]
```

and want to compare the 3rd elements of the comma-separated strings (so `"D"` or `"G"` or `"E"`) against doesn't have the contents of `arr2`. If that 3rd element is not equal to the element in `arr2`, I want to output the entire string from `arr1`.

I wrote this code but didn't give me the response that I need:

```
 for(var k=0 ; k<A.length ; k++){
    if(A[k].split(",")[2] !== E) {
       finalSuccessServices = A;
       console.log(finalSuccessServices );
     }
```

How can I fix my code to output lines that fit my goal above?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Please note that this is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to come up with your own approach. We can help you when you run into issues with that, but we are not here to write stuff for you.

Comment: That's not a valid JavaScript array. It looks more like an object, but objects are in `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar That's how Chrome and Firefox console.log arrays.

Comment: You don’t have individual values here, just a comma-separated string. So you could either split that to get an array first, so that you can access the third / last item explicitly, or you check if the whole string ends with `,E`. (Just checking if it ends with `E` might lead into trouble, if the actual data can be more complex, you might accidentally get a match on stuff like `X,Y,AE`.)

Comment: @misorude Actually I edit my code I wrote something but can't get the correct response that I need.

Comment: @Teemu I can't find my answer could you help me for solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to just check the third value of your comma separated string of arrays against the 0th element in your second array, the below snippet would suffice.

```js
const arr1 = ["B,C,D", "W,F,G", "M,S,E", "X,Y,Z"];
const arr2 = ["E"];

for( let ele of arr1 ) {
  if (arr2[0] !== ele.split(',')[2] ) {
    console.log('match', ele);
  }
}
```

Adding your code in question as snippet would make it easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish.